# Using value returned from a method in other method in java

Tags: java, jsp

Plz tell me how can we use value returned from one method in other method in jsp page..
I have two methods in jsp page as given below:

```
public String method1()
{
   dESEncryption = new DESEncryption();
   enteredValue = req.getParameter("t1");
   encryptedText = dESEncryption.encrypt(enteredValue);
   return encryptedValue;
}
```

I want to use this encryptedValue in other method public String method2(){}.How can I do it?Plz suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not really adviced to define methods like that in JSP. Better use tags for it or functions and try to keep your Java code out of your mark-up. This will keep your JSP code cleaner.

But if you really need to call another method then just do it like you do it in Java. [This article](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1010) has some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Simply this won't work?

```
public String method2()
{
String encryptedVal = method1();

}
```

Comment: actully i have used these functions in jsp page and these functions have to invoked on action of two buttons.i.e. method1() is to be invoked when i will click button1 and method2() is invoked when i will click button2. but when i am clicking button1 it calls both of the functions together and is not gives desired result.if i call the method1() for using returned value in method2(),it is invoked twice by button1.so i have confused that how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String method1()
{
   dESEncryption = new DESEncryption();
   enteredValue = req.getParameter("t1");
   encryptedText = dESEncryption.encrypt(enteredValue);
   return encryptedText;
}
```

You did not return the *encrypted* value, but the *original* text you got from the request. Also, be careful for any kinds of injections, your code can be prone to quite some nasty attacks without escaping every input...